# Google maps API V3 method fitBounds() using Prototypejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, prototypejs

I have a div as follows to display a google map:

```
#map {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 1px solid #DDD;
}

<div id="map"></div>
```

I want to display the map with a zoom level that fits the bounds of the above viewport.

When I code as follows it works fine:

```
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], {zoom: 10});

    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': generatedAddress }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                if (results[0].geometry.viewport)
                    map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);

      } else {
          alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
   });
```

When I use [typeahead-addresspicker.js](https://github.com/sgruhier/typeahead-addresspicker/blob/master/dist/typeahead-addresspicker.js) to generate the map it zooms in too far?

I've narrowed it down to the following code. When you call the `AddressPicker.prototype.updateMap` function the `boundsForLocation` option on `AddressPicker.prototype.initMap` function should return `this.map.fitBounds(response.geometry.viewport);` When I debug I can see that it is hitting the following code inside the `AddressPicker.prototype.updateBoundsForPlace` function as expected:

```
if (response.geometry.viewport) {
  console.log('test');
  return this.map.fitBounds(response.geometry.viewport);
}
```

What I don't understand is how it gets wired back to the google.maps.Map - I'm not familiar with ptototypejs? So basically running through it, we initilize the map by calling initMap, then we call the updateMap function. Inside updateMap function we are calling the following snippet of code:

```
if (_this.map) {
            if ((_ref = _this.mapOptions) != null) {
              _ref.boundsForLocation(response);
            }
   }
```

which is suppose to set the bounds by calling the `updateBoundsForPlace` but the [google maps options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) doesnt expose any property called boundsForLocation?

```
AddressPicker.prototype.initMap = function() {
    var markerOptions, _ref, _ref1;
    if ((_ref = this.options) != null ? (_ref1 = _ref.map) != null ? _ref1.gmap : void 0 : void 0) {
      this.map = this.options.map.gmap;
    } else {
      this.mapOptions = $.extend({
        zoom: 3,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        boundsForLocation: this.updateBoundsForPlace
      }, this.options.map);
      this.map = new google.maps.Map($(this.mapOptions.id)[0], this.mapOptions);
    }
    this.lastResult = null;
    markerOptions = $.extend({
      draggable: true,
      visible: false,
      position: this.map.getCenter(),
      map: this.map
    }, this.options.marker || {});
    this.marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);
    if (markerOptions.draggable) {
      return google.maps.event.addListener(this.marker, 'dragend', this.markerDragged);
    }
  };


  AddressPicker.prototype.updateMap = function(event, place) {
    if (this.options.placeDetails) {
      return this.placeService.getDetails(place, (function(_this) {
        return function(response) {
          var _ref;
          _this.lastResult = new AddressPickerResult(response);
          if (_this.marker) {
            _this.marker.setPosition(response.geometry.location);
            _this.marker.setVisible(true);
          }
          if (_this.map) {
            if ((_ref = _this.mapOptions) != null) {
              _ref.boundsForLocation(response);
            }
          }
          return $(_this).trigger('addresspicker:selected', _this.lastResult);
        };
      })(this));
    } else {
      return $(this).trigger('addresspicker:selected', place);
    }
  };

  AddressPicker.prototype.updateBoundsForPlace = function(response) {
    if (response.geometry.viewport) {
      return this.map.fitBounds(response.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      this.map.setCenter(response.geometry.location);
      return this.map.setZoom(this.options.zoomForLocation);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Is there any way you can make a fiddle to demonstrate the problem?  I am not really understanding what you are trying to ask.

Comment: In initMap this.map is being set to google maps:

this.map = this.options.map.gmap; 

or 

this.map = new google.maps.Map($(this.mapOptions.id)[0], this.mapOptions);

Comment: @Scott I understand that but when you call the updateMap function it needs to set boundsForLocation. But looking at the https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions api MapOptions doesnt have a property called boundsForLocation so how is it getting set?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix by commenting out the following lines:

```
//if (response.geometry.viewport) {
//  return this.map.fitBounds(response.geometry.viewport);
//} else {
  this.map.setCenter(response.geometry.location);
  return this.map.setZoom(this.options.zoomForLocation);
//}
```